# flutter cache SVG image

Tags: flutter, image, dart, svg, caching

I use svg_flutter and I want to cache my SVG network in the app.

can anyone help me please how can I do that?

here is my part of the code:

```
 SvgPicture.network(data[index]["Cat_Image"]),
```

I've just wanted to catch them.

Comment: see [precachePicture](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_svg/latest/svg/precachePicture.html)

Comment: @pskink I saw that but I was confused about how to use it for the widget. would you please help me ?

Comment: this is what they say in the docs: *"Returns a Future that will complete when the first image yielded by the PictureProvider is available or failed to load.

If the image is later used by an SvgPicture, it will probably be loaded faster. The consumer of the image does not need to use the same PictureProvider instance. The PictureCache will find the picture as long as both pictures share the same key."*

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a little method like:

```
Future<void> _precache() async {
    for (String imageUrl in _urls) {
      await precachePicture(
        NetworkPicture(
          SvgPicture.svgByteDecoderBuilder,
          imageUrl,
        ),
        null,
      );
    }
  }
```

This should be run before the start of the application, or before the widget is used at least. I'm using it in a provider created in runApp.

From my understanding, in the widget you would then have as normal:

```
SvgPicture.network(
  image_url,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code, it worked for me.

install `flutter_advanced_networkimage_2: ^2.0.1` package in pubspec.yaml

write the same code as given below:

```
SvgPicture(
            AdvancedNetworkSvg(
              'YOUR IMAGE URL',
              useDiskCache: true,
                  (theme) => (bytes, colorFilter, key) {
                return svg.svgPictureDecoder(
                  bytes ?? Uint8List.fromList(const []),
                  false,
                  colorFilter,
                  key,
                  theme: const SvgTheme(currentColor: Colors.green, xHeight: 20),
                );
              },
              loadFailedCallback: (){
                return SvgPicture.asset(
                  'placeholder or error image',
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                  width: 24,
                  height: 24,
                  color: Colors.red,
                );
              }
            ),
          )
```

Comment: How can i add a placeholder ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in main method

```
    await precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoderBuilder, 'assets/images/yourSvg.svg'), null);
```

Comment: and how to use it for the widget?

Comment: i want to use it in my class I want to use them

Comment: *"and how to use it for the widget?"* @user17838882 - i posted what the docs say: "If the image is **later used** by an `SvgPicture`, it will probably be loaded **faster**"

Comment: As @pskink said, precache it and use SvgPicture in the build method, flutter will automatically find the cache file and use it, if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [flutter_img](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_img) package.
here is a demo example. it will cache this image until you re-run your app

```
Img(
          'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shafi-org/portfolio/master/src/assets/flutter-svgrepo-com.svg',
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        ),
```